# Finding limit points and isolated points of a set

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

find limit points and isolated points of the following set:

$$A=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{E}^2: x=(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}, y=3, n\in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$

How should I proceed? I know that limit point is a point, that where if I put a sphere of arbitrary length, I should always get some point that belongs to the set. However, I fail to draw that function. (Still learning functions of two variables). How should I proceed without drawing the function?

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "I fail to draw that function".  You haven't mentioned a function here, so what exactly are you trying to draw?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You can imagine the set as a function of two variables. That's my understanding at least..

Comment: I don't know what you have in mind, but it sounds like your understanding is incorrect.  It is unclear what "imagining a set as a function of two variables" would entail.

Comment: If you are trying to draw a set then, what set is it exactly that you are trying to draw?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What I was trying to draw is: $f(x,y)=((-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1},3)$. But you are perhaps right, I think I don't understand the problem either. I'm just starting to learn similar problems. Could you help me?

Comment: I'll put an answer down.  A quick note though: $f(x,y) = ((-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1},3)$ doesn't make much sense; there is no $x$ or $y$ on the right side of the equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though the primary issue here is that of understanding the nature of the set $A$.  Note that we would normally read the definition presented as "$A$ is the set of all points $(x,y)$ (in $\Bbb E^2$) such that $x=(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+1}$ and $y=3$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$."  $\Bbb N$ here means the natural numbers $\Bbb N = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Because we have a point for each $n \in \Bbb N$, we can list the points.  We have
$$
n = 0: x = 0,y=3\\
n = 1: x = - \frac 12, y=3\\
n = 2: x = \frac 23, y = 3\\
n = 3: x = - \frac 34,y=3\\
\vdots
$$
In other words, our set contains the points $(0,3),(-1/2,3),(2/3,3),(-3/4,3),$ and so on.  In order to draw this set: make an $x$-axis and $y$-axis, then put a dot at each of the coordinates listed above.  Note that unlike a set associated with a function such as $\{(x,y): y = 2x - 3\}$, the set $A$ will consist of many separate dots instead of a line or a region.

Once you have drawn several of these coordinates for the set $A$, consider the following question: which circles can you draw that will capture infinitely many points? Which circles can you draw that will capture exactly one point?

Comment: Thanks! Also I think there are no interior points. Is it correct?

Comment: @Petra yes, that is correct.  In other words, there are no circles you can draw whose entire inside consists of points from $A$.

Comment: The second problem I'm solving is pretty much the same, but y is $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. So the solution for limit points is $(-1, m)$ and $(1,m)$? This is the last question, I swear..

Comment: @Petra no problem.  Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

For even $n$, the term $(-1)^n \frac{n}{n+1}$ is just $\frac{n}{n+1}= 1- \frac{1}{n+1}$. For odd $n$ we get the negative $-\frac{n}{n+1} = -1 + \frac{1}{n+1}$.

All these points are isolated but tend arbitarily close to $1$ (for even large values) and $-1$ (for odd large values).

In your case all these points lie on $y=3$, I just analysed their $x$-coordinates.

Conclusion: all points in the sequence are isolated and the two limit points are $(-1,3)$ and $(1,3)$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the isolated points. And regarding the limit points, the limits point are -1 and 1 because the sequence is converging to -1 and 1? Also are -1 and 1 isolated points?

Comment: @Petra because they are limits of subsequences with all distinct terms, they're limit points, not isolated.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now! One more question: There are no interior points, right?

Comment: @Petra no all open balls are uncountable so no countable set can have an interior that’s non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-$$\pm\dfrac{n}{n+1}=\pm\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac1n}\to \pm1$$ thus $(1,3)$ and $(-1,3)$ are limit points.

All the other are isolated because of $\left]\dfrac{n}{n+1},\dfrac{2n}{2n+1}\right[$ is a non empty open interval.

Thus all the $\left(-\dfrac{2n+1}{2n+2},3\right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{2n}{2n+1},3\right)$ are isolated points.